# What is the meaning of k in stock markets?

Tags: stock-markets

Now I'm studying the article ["Optimal High-Frequency Market Making"](http://stanford.edu/class/msande448/2018/Final/Reports/gr5.pdf). On page 3 there is a k in the formula of lambda for finding the number of the bid and ask executions by modeling them as a Poisson process. What is the k?

Comment: Are you sure you gave us the correct page?  I selected your link, went to page 3, and didn't see a formula with a k.  Please edit your question and add the formula in question.

Comment: On page 3: λ(δ) = Ae−κδ, assuming that's what he's referring to.

Comment: I think that's a Greek kappa, which may cause some confusion, but may also help with a google search to find out what it means.

Comment: Maybe try Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 4):

it is the rate of poisson process. Actually, k*t can be thought of as the expected number of events in the interval [0,t].

Answer (score -2):

K is the fifth letter added to a four letter Nasdaq stock symbol indicating that the stock has no voting right.
Or
One of the fifth letters that denote something specifically about the stock

Comment: I think this is answering a completely different question. The question is about the mathematics of market analysis, not ticker symbols.